# Is there a Way/tool to find label to drive mappings in FreeBSD?

Tags: mount, freebsd, label

Is there any facility in FreeBSD 8.4, where I can find a disk drive based on a label, similar to what `blkid` does in Linux? I am aware of `bsdlabel`, but it doesn't give me the drive based on label.

Can anyone throw some light on this? Or is there a facility to mount based on the label of the drive?

Answer (score 0):

Unmounted filesystems that are labeled can be found in subdirectories of `/dev/`. From glabel(8):

- UFS1 volume names (directory `/dev/ufs/`).
- UFS2 volume names (directory `/dev/ufs/`).
- UFS1 file system IDs (directory `/dev/ufsid/`).
- UFS2 file system IDs (directory `/dev/ufsid/`).
- MSDOSFS (FAT12, FAT16, FAT32) (directory `/dev/msdosfs/`).
- CD ISO9660 (directory `/dev/iso9660/`).
- EXT2FS (directory `/dev/ext2fs/`).
- REISERFS (directory `/dev/reiserfs/`).
- NTFS (directory `/dev/ntfs/`).

You can use these labels for mounting the filesystems.